# rpy2, R eegAnalysis & time series error

Tags: time-series, rpy2

Working with a relatively new R package called "eegAnalysis" through rpy2 and getting an error for a time-series object required by the FeatureEEG function.

```
table_query = R_DBI.dbGetQuery(DBI_Connection, "SELECT * FROM {0}".format(a_table))
```

where table_query is returned from a PostgreSQL database, a small portion of the data looks like

'data.frame':   52000 obs. of  68 variables:
lfg1 : num  205 200 185 183 175 ...
lfg10: num  -135.1 -124.1 -127.1 -116.1 -80.1 ...
lfg11: num  -132 -109 -101 -103 -116 ...
lfg12: num  -259 -246 -232 -196 -203 ...

soon there-after a time-series object is created using table_query from above

```
ts = R_ts.timeSeries(table_query, start = 1, end = table_query.nrow, frequency = 1)
```

several lines below used for the important line even further below

```
n_columns = ts.ncol
col_middle = n_columns / 2
if round(col_middle) != col_middle:
    col_middle = col_middle + 0.5
group_1 = int(col_middle)
group_2 = int(n_columns - group_1)
classification = R_base.c(R_base.rep(1, group_1), R_base.rep(2, group_2))
```

the important line is here

```
featureEEG = R_EEGA.FeatureEEG(ts, rec_Id = ts.nrow, classes_Id = classification)
```

FeatureEEG is a function from the R eegAnalysis package. After processing for a few moments the 
following error is returned

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "D:\Projects\Kaggle\UPenn_and_Mayo_Clinic_Seizure_Detection\Scripts\py_test01.py", line 135, in  featureEEG = R_EEGA.FeatureEEG(ts, rec_Id = ts.nrow, classes_Id = classification) File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.3.8-py3.3-win32.egg\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 86, in **call** return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).**call**(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.3.8-py3.3-win32.egg\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 35, in **call** res = super(Function, self).**call**(*new_args, **new_kwargs) rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in UseMethod("months") :  no applicable method for 'months' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"*

From what I can tell, the line creating featureEEG is processed, and it is in the processing where 
the error occurs. Most of the message is understandable except for the part starting at the 
RRuntimeError. Could someone explain what it is saying? Or where can I find out?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The `RRuntimeError` is reporting an error message generated by R.

Here it appears to try calling a generic `months()`. I am suspecting that `ts` in your code is not of the right type. The authors of `eegAnalysis` might be able to help.

Comment: Hello! Fiddled with the code and discovered several things I had coded incorrectly. Still not getting it to run however -- stuck at "'ts' object must have one or more observations". I'm guessing the table_query object is not having its' data recognized as 'observation' when converted into a timeSeries (ts) object. I'll check with the author to find out what type of object is required.